# Freewheel with lock ring, what is this?

Tags: freewheel, freehub

I rescued a bike from the trash and want to convert from 7 speed to 9 speed.  The biggest sprocket has "Lock Ring Type" printed on, so I assumed it was a 7 speed cassette (and I wanted to see if the free hub is a modern type that fits a 9 speed cassette).

However after taking the wheel out I noticed it looks like a freewheel rather than freehub with cassette.  Why does it say "Lock Ring Type" on the biggest sprocket?  Is this actually a freehub with a lockring that's unfamiliar to me?

I have included a picture (I removed the axle to have a closer look).
[image: Cassette or freewheel]

Comment: It is https://www.bike24.com/p2273122.html

Comment: "megadrive" sounds like a knock off of the Shimano MegaRange freewheels with a very large low gear.

Comment: Pure speculation on my part but perhaps disassembly requires removal of the ring marked "Suunrace M1"  using a suitable (but unknown)  tool, instead of the typical 2 pin spanner on the more inner ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a freewheel with some words on it. The tool splines will always spin with the cogs if it's a cassette.

Comment: Do you expect the “lock ring type” to just be some nonsense marketing?

Comment: I suspect it's some kind of knockoff off the Shimano "Mega 7" design, which used a lockring instead of threaded cogs. https://www.sheldonbrown.com/mega7/